# ¿Cómo obtener la suma total de una columna MySQL en un TextView de Android Studio con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, json, recyclerview

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con obtener la suma de una columna de MySQL en una TexView de Android Studio utilizando PHP, en principio tengo que mencionar que estoy trabajando con un `RecyClerView` en donde obtengo productos, cada vez que yo presiono sobre un producto mi carrito de comprar se incremente en 1, anteriormente ya he obtenido la cantidad de productos que se almacenan en la base de datos ahora lo que hice es hacer el conteo de esa cantidad de productos y obtenerlos en un `TexView` de Android estudio (En este caso el carrito de compras) ya tengo el código hecho en Android y la consulta en PHP (Que posteriormente mostraré el procedimiento) en principio cuando agrego un producto esto solo incrementa una vez, cuando agrego otro el contador se queda en 1 y no sube más y el segundo problema radica en una excepción benigna la cual es la siguiente:

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"TotalProductos":[{"TotalProductos":"1.00"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Esta es mi consulta PHP

```
<?php

require 'conn.php';

$id_prefactura=$_GET["id_prefactura"];

$result= mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(cantidad_producto) as TotalProductos FROM 
fac_det_prefactura WHERE id_prefactura = $id_prefactura");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['TotalProductos'];

 if($result)
{
 $data[]['TotalProductos'] = $sum;

 echo json_encode(array("TotalProductos" => $data));
}

?>
```

Mi clase java

```
public class ContadorProductos {

public static class GetDataFromServerIntoTextView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public Context context;
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String StringHolder = "" ;
    String contador_url = "http://pedidoslab.atspace.cc/contadorProdPedidos.php" + "?id_prefactura=" + Login.gIdPedido;

    public GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(contador_url);

        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            StringHolder = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(StringHolder);
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        try {

            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(StringHolder));

            //Aqui es donde le estoy asignando el resultado convertido a JSON para poderlo mostrar en un TexView cada que yo selecciono un producto.
ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf
(responseJSON.getJSONArray("TotalProductos").length())); 
            
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema es que esto no es un JSONArray: `{"TotalProductos":[{"TotalProductos":"1.00"}]}` es un JSONObject. La diferencia es que uno empieza por `[` y el otro empieza por `{`. Tu problema debería resolverse, **a medias**, mandando un JSONArray desde el servidor: `echo json_encode($data);` Ahí sí estarías recibiendo un `JSONArray`. Aunque tampoco veo que hagas nada con el dato en Android, pero ese es otro tema, así como decidir si realmente lo que se necesita aquí es un JSONArray. ¿Esperas varios datos que recorrerías luego con un bucle? Si no es así, no se justifica un array aquí.

Comment: A pesar de que no soluciono completamente mi problema gracias a tu respuesta pude encontrar ciertos detalles que me llevaron a resolverlo completamente por mi cuenta, muchas gracias, hubiera sido bueno que le pusieras como respuesta para marcarla como util, saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) no es otra cosa que un formato de intercambio de datos con una estructura muy definida y muy simple basada en **dos tipos de estructuras** (object y array) y **seis tipos de datos** (object, array, string, number, boolean y null).

### Estructuras

En un JSON los datos pueden venir organizados en dos tipos de estructuras:

- **object** (objeto): Un objeto es un conjunto desordenado de pares de nombre / valor.

  Un objeto comienza con <kbd>`{`</kbd> *llave izquierda* y termina con <kbd>`}`</kbd> *llave derecha*.

  Cada nombre va seguido de <kbd>`:`</kbd> *dos puntos*.

  Los pares de nombre / valor están separados por una <kbd>`,`</kbd> *coma*.

  Esta sería una persona, expresada en JSON:

  ```
   {
      "persona":{
         "nombre":"Pedro",
         "apellido":"Díaz"
      }
  ```

---

- **array** (matriz): Una matriz es una colección ordenada de valores.

  Comienza con <kbd>`[`</kbd> *corchete izquierdo* y termina con <kbd>`]`</kbd> *corchete derecho*.

  Los valores están separados por <kbd>`,`</kbd> coma.

  Por lo general en los arrays se incluyen colecciones de objetos que luego pueden ser leídos en un bucle u obtenidos en base a un índice específico. Esas colecciones pueden ser de cualquiera de los seis tipos de datos que existen en JSON.

  Este sería un array de personas (objetos) expresado en JSON:

  ```
      {
         "personas":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "nombre":"Pedro",
               "apellido":"Díaz",
               "hijos":[
                  "Juan",
                  "María"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "nombre":"Marta",
               "apellido":"López",
               "hijos":[
                  "Ana",
                  "José",
                  "Lucía"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
  ```

  En este ejemplo vemos un poco más de complejidad, pero siempre dentro de la simplicidad de JSON. `personas` es un array de objetos: `[ {...}, {...} ]` y a su vez `hijos` es un array de cadenas: `["...", "..."]`. Por tanto, los arrays pueden ser de cualquiera de los seis tipos de datos  como dijimos más arriba. `hijos` podría ser perfectamente un array de objetos, cada uno con su `id`, `nombre`, etc...

### Tipos de datos

Un valor puede ser una cadena entre comillas dobles, un número, verdadero, falso, nulo, un objeto o una matriz. Estas estructuras se pueden anidar.

- **object** (objeto): `{ ... }`
- **array** (matriz): `[ ... ]`
- **string** (cadena): `"Lorem ipsum"`
- **number** (número): `8`
- **boolean** (booleano): `true` o `false`
- **null** (nulo) : `null`

---

## Resolviendo el problema

Lo descrito anteriormente, aunque parece que no tiene nada que ver con tu problema, sí lo tiene. Porque el origen del problema es **no entender JSON**. Conociendo las pocas líneas de más arriba tendrás un doctorado en JSON y no será difícil leer, desde cualquier lenguaje, usando los métodos disponibles para ello, cualquier estructura JSON por compleja que ésta sea, porque un JSON se puede anidar hasta muchos niveles, pero siempre dentro de la simplicidad de lo antes explicado.

Aplicando lo dicho, si analizamos lo indicado en el mensaje de error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value
> {"TotalProductos":[{"TotalProductos":"1.00"}]} of type
> org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Vemos que tienes la siguiente estructura:

```
{
   "TotalProductos":[
      {
         "TotalProductos":"1.00"
      }
   ]
}
```

Nuestro doctorado nos permite describirla, empezando a leer desde lo primero que vemos que es una `{`. Por tanto: *tenemos un **objeto** (`JSONObject` en el contexto de Java) con una clave `TotalProductos`. Y en esa clave tenemos un **array** (`JSONArray` en el contexto de Java), el cual tiene dentro otro **objeto**, con un valor del tipo **string** (`1.00`) asociado a la clave `TotalProductos`*.

La descripción parece un trabalengua, pero eso es porque el JSON en sí lo es... pero ese es otro asunto. Quizá para tu caso convendría una estructura más simple, por ejemplo:

```
{
   "TotalProductos":"1.00"
}
```

Me he alargado demasiado... pero si entiendes JSON evitarás ir dando tumbos en los programas y podrás organizar mejor las respuestas en el servidor, consumiendo los datos de una forma simple.

La cuestión es que: **si esperas en respuesta un arrray, tienes que usar la clase `JSONArray` para leer esa respuesta; si en cambio esperas un objeto, tienes que usar la clase `JSONObject` para leer esa respuesta**. Lo mismo para la lectura de cualquiera de esos elementos del JSON... Por eso el mensaje de error te decía: *`... of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`*, porque en algún punto estabas intentando leer un object `{ ... }` como si fuese un array `[ ... ]`.

La forma en la que organices tus datos depende de ti. Pero te recuerdo que JSON existe para facilitar la vida, no para complicarla.

### Una herramienta imprescindible

Puede haber JSON muy grandes y con varios niveles de anidación. Para esos casos conviene una herramienta que nos permita analizarlos por parte si quisiéramos.

Existen muchos validadores de JSON en línea que pueden sernos de gran ayuda. Este es mi preferido: [`jsonformatter`](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Nos dice en primer lugar si el JSON es válido, algo fundamental que debemos verificar antes de querer leer cualquier JSON en cualquier programa. Y luego con los símbolos de <kbd>+</kbd> y de <kbd>-</kbd> nos permite recoger o desplegar partes del JSON para facilitar el análisis del mismo.

Si el JSON tiene errores, también nos lo dice, y nos dice cuál es el motivo y dónde se encuentran esos errores para que podamos corregirlo allí mismo si fuera preciso.

La **validación** es importante, pues es algunos puedes pasarte horas tratando de hacer funcionar un código, cuando el problema es que el JSON no es válido, y ese código nunca funcionará, aunque esté bien escrito, si el JSON es inválido.

Comment: Muchas gracias aunque solucione el contador del producto aun tenia la excepción que no me dejaba tranquilo y esto me ha funcionado muy bien para quitar dicha excepción gracias por tomarte el tiempo!!