# ¿Cómo estructuro un JSON para generar vistas HTML a partir de ellos?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

He estado viendo videos donde leen archivos.json y los imprimen en una tabla.

De allí nace mi inquietud: ¿Se puede almacenar varias cadenas de texto para un objeto?

Es decir algo similar a:

```
[
    {
      "obj1" = "línea1"
              "línea2"
              "líneaN"
    },
    {
     "obj2" = "línea1"
              "línea2"
              "línea3"
              "líneaN"
    }
    ...
]
```

Me imagino que si es posible leerlas mediante el objeto, se las podría mostrar en el html.

Todo esto viene a cuento de lo siguiente: hice una plantilla html y también tengo un archivo que primeramente lo leo y luego quiero mostrar las líneas (que vendrían a estar dentro de una `<ul>` y a su vez cada una en un `<li>`) que mediante id's de los div tengo acceso para cambiar el contenido.

Comment: Cual es el problema especificamente?

Comment: mira hice una plantilla html y tambien tengo un archivo que primeramente lo leo y luego quiero mostrar las líneas (que vendrían a estar dentro de una <ul> y a su vez cada una en un <li> ) que mediante id's de los div tengo acceso para cambiar el contenido. Soy nuevo en esta parte y la verdad no he usado antes json y/o ajax solo javascript puro y no tengo idea de como cargar la informacion que tengo en el archivo.

Comment: ¿Realmente hace falta cerrar la pregunta tras dos semanas? Produjo una respuesta muy buena, fue útil para el usuario, puede serlo para otros... Voto para reabrir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo primero que conviene tener claro es que JSON es algo **muy, muy simple** y que es una forma de organizar datos de manera estructurada y a la vez ligera. Y generalmente esa organización de datos se hace para unos fines concretos, para representar entidades, etc.

Luego, un JSON puede ser más o menos anidado, conteniendo dentro cadenas, números, booleanos, arrays u otros objetos JSON, pero **los tipos de datos son muy pocos y funcionan todos igual según su tipo**, así que un JSON, por anidado que sea, no debería se complicado, a no ser que quien lo diseñe o genere lo complique por desconocimiento<sup>1</sup>.

Por tanto, cuando diseñes un JSON tienes que pensar también en que éste pueda ser leído (consumido) sin que cause una indigestión al cliente (sea complicadísimo de leer).

Para el caso que expones, si tú usas `obj1`, `obj2`, `objN` **como nombres de clave** ya estás creando un JSON que será muy difícil de leer, porque **para acceder al contenido de las claves tendrás que conocerlas de antemano** cosa harto difícil porque quizá nunca sepas cuántos `obj` habrá.

Ese JSON concreto se hace digerible **creando una clave que será la misma para todos los objetos**. Así ya sabes que esa clave se llamará igual, haya un objeto o haya mil y podrás ir a buscar la información por esa clave. En el ejemplo dimos los nombres: `nombre` y `valor` a todos los objetos que hay en el array principal.

En cuanto a tu duda sobre las líneas, lo más simple, cuando vayas a guardar listas de valores sin más, es que los pongas en un array. Así podrás usar funciones del lenguaje que consume los datos para leerlos fácilmente, según necesites. Por ejemplo aquí usamos `map()` y `join()` para mostrar las líneas una por una y con un tabulador. **Como hicimos eso, podremos crear tablas, celdas, listas o lo que sea, usando las herramientas adecuadas**.

Veamos un ejemplo de código en el que, con dos líneas de Javascript consumimos el JSON sin indigestión y sin tener que recurrir a trucos oscuros para adivinar cómo se llama tal clave del objeto y luego sacar sus datos.

```js
var mData=`[
   {
      "nombre":"obj1",
      "valores":[
         "línea1",
         "línea2",
         "líneaN"
      ]
   },
   {
      "nombre":"obj2",
      "valores":[
         "línea1",
         "línea2",
         "líneaN"
      ]
   }
]`;

var mJson=JSON.parse(mData);
var str="";
for (var i=0; i<mJson.length; i++){
  str+=mJson[i].nombre+"\n";
  str+=mJson[i].valores.map(x => "\t"+ x).join("\n")+"\n";        
}
console.log(str);
```

Vamos a crear una lista, verás que simple:

```js
var mData=`[
   {
      "nombre":"obj1",
      "valores":[
         "línea1",
         "línea2",
         "líneaN"
      ]
   },
   {
      "nombre":"obj2",
      "valores":[
         "línea1",
         "línea2",
         "líneaN"
      ]
   }
]`;

var mJson=JSON.parse(mData);
var str="<ul>";
for (var i=0; i<mJson.length; i++){
  str+=`<li>${mJson[i].nombre}`;
  str+=`<ul>${mJson[i].valores.map(x => "<li>"+ x+"</li>").join("")}</ul></li>`;        
}
str+=`</ul>`;
//console.log(str);


document.getElementById('miLista').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
```

```html
<div id="miLista">
</div>
```

Esto es lo que se crea y se agrega al `div` a modo de prueba:

```
<ul>
  <li>obj1
    <ul>
      <li>línea1</li>
      <li>línea2</li>
      <li>líneaN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>obj2
    <ul>
      <li>línea1</li>
      <li>línea2</li>
      <li>líneaN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Notas

1. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967) he tratado de explicar con más detalle la estructura de un JSON. Conociendo eso, no deberás tener problema para diseñar / analizar / leer cualquier JSON en cualquier contexto.

Comment: gracias ya modifique mi archivo json y lo pude leer talvez luego tenga otra inquietud y haga otra pregunta en el foro.