# Tengo problemas para agregar elementos a un arreglo multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, web

He buscado tópicos publicados anteriormente y resuelven en arreglos mas sencillos, pero no aplican al arreglo que tengo, debo hacer una comparación y si el elemento **"dc"** es igual a **54000** insertar debajo de él **"ac"=1**.
*El arreglo que tengo es el siguiente:*

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "geometries": [
          {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  -98.50787641015751,
                  21.0569205444831,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -98.5068492701624,
                  21.0571512440413,
                  0
                ]
              ]
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  -98.45522575786653,
                  21.08383085619691,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -98.45258111365344,
                  21.07583530797188,
                  0
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        ],
        "type": "GeometryCollection"
      },
      "properties": {
        "dc": 45000
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -98.3724008202337,
              21.0997012494585,
              0
            ],
            [
              -98.37192478032108,
              21.0997454193106,
              0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "dc": 46000
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "geometries": [
          {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  -98.35061900000001,
                  20.087859,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -98.349991,
                  20.087992,
                  0
                ]
              ]
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  -98.0267970904471,
                  20.583530339752,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -98.0250023106026,
                  20.5776239002342,
                  0
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        ],
        "type": "GeometryCollection"
      },
      "properties": {
        "dc": 58000
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

El código que llevo me permite listar el contenido completo del arreglo, pero no los elementos por separado, menos he encontrado como hacer push si es que se puede en el medio de un arreglo.
Les pongo mi código:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("muestra.json");
$arreglo = json_decode($data, true);
//Muestro el arreglo inicial
foreach ($mapa_virgen as $elemento) {

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($elemento);
    echo '</pre>';
}

//Agrego un elemento
foreach ($mapa_virgen as $elemento) {

    if($elemento==45000){
         array_push($arreglo, "ac", 1);
         }
}

?>
```

Como menciono antes, la idea es que pueda elegir insertar o no un elemento nuevo que sería ac, dependiendo del valor dc, si es 45000 debería insertar ac con valor de 1, si dc no tiene ese valor, no se insertaría nada y seguiría el recorrido del arreglo hasta encontrar otro dc con valor de 45000.
Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano les agradezco el apoyo.
Espero enviar todo lo necesario para para que se entienda mi problema, cualquier cosa estaré al pendiente, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es `$mapa_virgen`? El dato que buscas se encuentra dentro de una propiedad `dc` que a su vez está dentro de una propiedad llamada `properties`.  Suponiendo que `$elemento` apunta correctamente, la forma de acceder sería: `$elemento['properties']['dc']`

Comment: Mil disculpas, un error al copiar, $mapa_virgen no existe, es $arreglo en lugar de ello, reviso lo que me comentas a ver si funciona, gracias.

Comment: No funcionó como me indicas o algo me falta que es más problable. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

Comment: <?php
$data = file_get_contents("muestra.json");
$arreglo = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($arreglo as $clave => $valor) {
 if ($arreglo['properties']['dc']==45000){
  echo "comparación exitosa.";
  }
}
?>

Comment: Me arroja los siguientes errores: Warning: Undefined array key "properties" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key "properties" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer tus datos como un JSON sin más, sin tener que convertirlo a array.

En la pregunta se ve que quieres acceder a los elementos que hay dentro del array `features` del objeto. Entonces puedes hacerlo así simplemente:

```
$data = file_get_contents("muestra.json");

#No pasamos true para que sea un json
$mData = json_decode($data); 

#Al pasar $item como referencia, podremos modificarlo
foreach($mData->features as &$item){
    if($item->properties->dc==45000){
        $item->properties->ac=1;
    }      
}
```

Si observas, al trabajarlo como objeto usamos la notación `$objeto->propiedad` que es mucho más clara.

Otra clave importante es que al pasar `&$item` por referencia (por eso la `&`), luego, dentro del bucle, podemos modificarlo agregándole la propiedad `ac` cuando haga falta.

De ese modo debería funcionar, salvo otros errores en tu código.

La propiedad modificada quedará así:

```
  ["properties"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["dc"]=>
    int(45000)
    ["ac"]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

### Post-Data

A veces los JSON anidados impresionan y rápidamente uno se encuentra perdido dentro de una estructura compleja. Si embargo, **JSON es una forma muy simple de organizar datos**. Usa muy pocos tipos de datos los cuales pueden contener a su vez otros tipos de datos y puedes acceder a ellos de manera general o parcial **siguiendo la ruta correcta**. En este caso concreto, la ruta que debes seguir es: `features->properties->dc`  y allí está el dato que buscas, sólo falta leerlo, según lo que tenga el padre. De modo que si `features` el padre de `properties` es un array (representado por `[`, lo leerás como array y si `properties` el padre de `dc` es un objeto json, lo leerás como tal, encontrando allí a `dc` que es el dato que buscas.

[En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967) he tratado de explicar una forma simple de entender JSON. Si sabes distinguir de qué tipo es cada cosa, podrás leer cualquier JSON por más anidado o complicado que parezca.

Comment: Genial, me quedó muy claro, lo haré así, te agradezco mucho la ayuda!!!

Comment: @JuanOrtega recomiendo que leas la nota que puse al final y el enlace. Si logras entender eso no tendrás problema en el futuro para descifrar cualquier JSON, por más anidado que éste sea.

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente la ayuda, en efecto comprendí más acerca de los Json con la respuesta agregada, mil gracias por la ayuda, saludos y que tengas muy buena tarde.