# Asignar datos Json a variables PHP

Tags: php, json

necesito asignar este json a variables php. No he logrado hacerlos.

Estos datos y formato los tomo de un teléfono ip grandstream.

Básicamente me interesa rescatar los datos state y remotenumber

Agradecería mucho si me dan una mano.

Este es el Json

```
{
  "response": "success",
  "body": [
    {
      "line": 1,
      "state": "idle",
      "acct": 1,
      "active": 0,
      "remotename": "",
      "remotenumber": ""
    },
    {
      "line": 2,
      "state": "idle",
      "acct": 1,
      "active": 0,
      "remotename": "",
      "remotenumber": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `json_decode($string, true);` convierte un *string json* en *array* - [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php). Si el json es un archivo, lo puedes leer primero con [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando trabajas con JSON (sea cual sea el lenguaje de programación), lo más importante es que entiendas a JSON en sí mismo. Es una forma muy simple de organizar datos que pueden estar anidados de una forma muy compleja, pero por más compleja que sea la estructura, leerla es muy simple porque **¡JSON es simple!**.

Para el caso que expones: *Básicamente me interesa rescatar los datos state y remotenumber*.

Si analizamos el JSON, nos vamos al **padre** donde están los datos que te interesan. Vemos que es `body` y vemos ademas que `body` contiene un array (lo sabemos porque empieza por `[`) y que ese array contiene objetos json (lo sabemos porque tiene dentro elementos así: `{...}, {...}`). Hecho ese análisis, ya sabremos como leerlo.

Cada lenguaje tiene sus herramientas para obtener/leer JSON. En el caso de PHP cuentas con [**`json_decode()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php). El modo de obtener el JSON ya depende de cada contexto (puedes usar `file_get_contents, cURL, una llamada a una API, a un servicio en la nube, un archivo, una base de datos, una cadena ... o lo que sea). Aquí nos centramos en el JSON.

`json_decode()` te permite trabajar el JSON como un objeto (yo lo prefiero así porque hay menos manipulación en los datos y porque la forma de lectura es más clara), para ello invocas `json_decode()` pasándole sólamente el contenido del JSON. Y te permite también convertir el JSON a array (pero esto casi nunca es necesario). Para convertirlo a array le pasarías `true` en segundo parámetro a `json_decode()`.

Entendido eso, y sabiendo que quieres obtener los datos que hay en `state` y en `remotenumber` podemos hacer algo así:

```
/*
    Aquí pongo el JSON como una cadena
    porque no estoy en tu contexto
    Ajusta esta parte a tu contexto, dependiendo de como obtienes el JSON
*/
$srcJSON='
{
  "response": "success",
  "body": [
    {
      "line": 1,
      "state": "idle",
      "acct": 1,
      "active": 0,
      "remotename": "",
      "remotenumber": "1"
    },
    {
      "line": 2,
      "state": "idle",
      "acct": 1,
      "active": 0,
      "remotename": "",
      "remotenumber": "2"
    }
  ]
}';

/*
    No pasamos true en 2º parámetro
    porque nos interesa el JSON en sí
    no un array
*/
$mJSON=json_decode($srcJSON);

/*
    Los datos que te interesan están en body
    Y accederías a body de este modo $mJSON->body
    PERO lo que hay en body es un array ...
    haremos esto a modo de prueba
*/
$mBody=$mJSON->body;
var_dump($mBody);
```

La salida de nuestra prueba es esta (he puesto valores a `remotenumber` para la prueba:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
    ["line"]=>
    int(1)
    ["state"]=>
    string(4) "idle"
    ["acct"]=>
    int(1)
    ["active"]=>
    int(0)
    ["remotename"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["remotenumber"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
    ["line"]=>
    int(2)
    ["state"]=>
    string(4) "idle"
    ["acct"]=>
    int(1)
    ["active"]=>
    int(0)
    ["remotename"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["remotenumber"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Habiendo visto la parte que nos interesa como un objeto PHP, podemos pasar a leerlo mediante código PHP.

```
/*
    Aquí, el array que es body tiene dos elementos
    los cuales son objetos JSON (podría tener más ... o menos)
    Ahora debes decidir si quieres todos los elementos
    o si quieres uno en específico.
    Si los quieres todos, los puedes obtener leyendo a body en un bucle
    Si quieres uno en específico puedes acceder a él por su índice
    Veamos ejemplos de ambos casos
*/

#Leer todos
foreach($mJSON->body as $item) {
    echo "{$item->state} {$item->remotenumber}".PHP_EOL; # idle 1  y idle 2
}                                                           

#Leer uno en específico, por el índice
echo "{$mJSON->body[0]->state} {$mJSON->body[0]->remotenumber}";  # idle 1
```

Entendiendo el JSON, podrás leer cualquier parte de él o cualquier propiedad.

---

#### Enlace recomendado

- En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967) yo he explicado con más detalle la estructura de un JSON. Comprendiendo eso (son unas pocas líneas) tendrás un doctorado en JSON y podrás entender/leer cualquier estructura JSON sin ningún problema, por más compleja que sea.