# Error: Illegal string offset PHP

Tags: php, json, php7, foreach

Estoy utilizando la API de meaningcloud para analizar un texto, la respuesta la devuelve en un JSON con muchos campos que realmente no utilizaré.
[image: Ejemplo de lo que me devuelve la API]

Únicamente utilizare esos "score_tag" y el "text".
La cuestión es que para únicamente capturar esos datos, lo he hecho con un foreach (lo he utilizado otras veces y nunca me había dado problemas).
Pero ahora me devuelve el error "Illegal string offset".
Alguien sabe o tiene alguna idea de por qué me da ese error?
Dejo el código aquí:

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","comentarios");
$result =mysqli_query($link, "SELECT comentario From comentarios");

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $comentario=$profile['comentario']; //el comentario que trae de la BD


    $response = $client->post('https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1', [
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'key',
                'contents' => 'API_KEY'
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'txt',
                'contents' => $comentario
                
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'lang',
                'contents' => 'es'
            ]        
        ]
    ]);

    $status = $response->getStatusCode();
    $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

    //header ("Content-Type: JSON");

    foreach ($body as $row) {
    $tag = $row['score_tag']; //score_tag es el nombre de lo que quiero del JSON
    echo $tag;
    }
} //llave del while

?>
```

Comment: No estás haciendo referencia a `sentence_list`, que es la clave donde están los datos: **`foreach ($body["sentence_list"] as $row) {`** Si no te funciona haz un `var_dump($body);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Padre Cedano, muchísimas gracias por su respuesta, me acaba de quitar horas de amargura y sufrimiento. Me trae justo lo que necesito, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si analizas la respuesta, verás que los datos se encuentran dentro de esta clave en el JSON:

```
"sentence_list" : [
    { },
    { }
]
```

Significa que tienes que hacer referencia a esa clave para obtener el array de objetos:

```
foreach ($body["sentence_list"] as $row) {
    //Lectura de cada objeto
}
```

Además, puedes obtener los datos como objetos en vez de array, y usar la sintaxis `$objeto->propiedad` para la lectura, para ello solamente dejas de pasar `true` en segundo parámetro a `json_decode`:

```
$body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

//header ("Content-Type: JSON");

foreach ($body->sentence_list as $row) {
    $tag = $row->score_tag; 
    echo $tag;
}
```

**MUY IMPORTANTE:**

Te recomiendo que leas [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967). Si entiendes lo que se dice allí (aunque no es una pregunta sobre PHP), ¡tendrás un doctorado en JSON! y serás capaz de analizar cualquier JSON, por complejo que sea, y adaptar tu código a su lectura sin ninguna dificultad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya probé ambos métodos y los 2 me funcionaron. Al terminar lo que estoy haciendo le echaré un vistazo a lo que me pasó de JSON.
Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!