# Como puedo extraer informacion de $curl php

Tags: php, api

Soy nuevo en esto y no encuentro como puedo extraer información de lo siguiente
mi código

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://queries.envia.com/locale',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

me arroja lo siguiente

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"value":20.083586,"currency":"MXN","country_code":"MX","country_name":"Mexico"},{"id":2,"value":3863.557063,"currency":"COP","country_code":"CO","country_name":"Colombia"},{"id":3,"value":1,"currency":"USD","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States of America"},{"id":4,"value":5.2001,"currency":"BRL","country_code":"BR","country_name":"Brazil"},{"id":5,"value":0.848664,"currency":"EUR","country_code":"ES","country_name":"Spain"},{"id":6,"value":96.2414,"currency":"ARS","country_code":"AR","country_name":"Argentina"},{"id":7,"value":762.209764,"currency":"CLP","country_code":"CL","country_name":"Chile"},{"id":8,"value":43.750191,"currency":"UYU","country_code":"UY","country_name":"Uruguay"},{"id":9,"value":7.748032,"currency":"GTQ","country_code":"GT","country_name":"Guatemala"},{"id":10,"value":1.25803,"currency":"CAD","country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada"},{"id":11,"value":74.415003,"currency":"INR","country_code":"IN","country_name":"India"},{"id":14,"value":3.932402,"currency":"PEN","country_code":"PE","country_name":"Peru"},{"id":15,"value":6.42,"currency":"CNY","country_code":"CN","country_name":"China"},{"id":16,"value":1.28,"currency":"AUD","country_code":"AU","country_name":"Australia"},{"id":21,"value":108.84,"currency":"JPY","country_code":"JP","country_name":"Japan"},{"id":22,"value":74.35,"currency":"RUB","country_code":"RU","country_name":"Russian Federation"}]}
```

como hago para obtener sienta información con php, perdonen mi ignorancia

Answer (score 1):

Tu respuesta cURL es un objeto JSON con una clave `data`, la cual contiene a su vez un array con varios objetos JSON. Esto se puede determinar fácilmente al analizar la estructura de la respuesta JSON:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "value":20.083586,
            "currency":"MXN",
            "country_code":"MX",
            "country_name":"Mexico"
        },
        {
            ... etc ...
        },
        {
            "id":22,
            "value":74.35,
            "currency":"RUB",
            "country_code":"RU",
            "country_name":"Russian Federation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Al analizar vemos esto: `{ }`, que en JSON representará siempre un objeto, mientras que esto `[ ]` representará siempre un array.

Entendido eso, podrás leer el contenido haciendo lo siguiente:

- Primero debes convertir la respuesta a JSON mediante [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), ya que la respuesta de cURL es siempre una cadena.
- Ya convertido a JSON, obtienes los datos que quieras, según esté estructurado al objeto.

Si, como dijimos antes, tienes un objeto JSON bajo la clave `data` y dentro de `data` tienes un array de objetos con sus propiedades: `id, value, currency`, etc.

Una lectura posible sería esta:

```
$json=json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->data as $item) {
    echo "$item->id $item->value $item->currency".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1 20.083586 MXN
2 3863.557063 COP
3 1 USD
4 5.2001 BRL
5 0.848664 EUR
6 96.2414 ARS
7 762.209764 CLP
8 43.750191 UYU
9 7.748032 GTQ
10 1.25803 CAD
11 74.415003 INR
14 3.932402 PEN
15 6.42 CNY
16 1.28 AUD
21 108.84 JPY
22 74.35 RUB
```

Aquí `$item` será cada objeto JSON dentro del array que hay en `data` y usamos sus propiedades para obtener los datos que hay en ellas. He usado sólo algunas propiedades, a modo de ejemplo, las demás las puedes obtener mediante la notación `$objeto->propiedad` ...

Si por el contrario, quieres obtener los datos de un objeto específico, puedes lograrlo usando el índice de dicho objeto. Supongamos que quieres el elemento con `id=7`, el mismo estará en la posición `6` del array de objetos JSON (los arrays empiezan a indexarse desde `0`).

```
$oneItem=$json->data[6];
var_dump($oneItem);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#7 (5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(7)
  ["value"]=>
  float(762.209764)
  ["currency"]=>
  string(3) "CLP"
  ["country_code"]=>
  string(2) "CL"
  ["country_name"]=>
  string(5) "Chile"
}
```

En la salida anterior vemos tu objeto con id=7. Ahora, si quieres sacar sus datos puedes usar la notación: `$objeto->propiedad`, por ejemplo:

```
echo $oneItem->id.PHP_EOL;
echo $oneItem->country_code.PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
7
CL
```

JSON es muy simple de entender. Si quieres saber cómo leer un objeto JSON, por más anidado que esté, sólo tienes que analizarlo. [Te dejo aquí el enlace a una respuesta en la que he tratado de explicar la estructura de todo elemento JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967). Si entiendes eso, tendrás un doctorado en JSON y ninguno podrá resistirse, por complejo que sea. Otra herramienta muy útil para analizar JSON es [esta página](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) que te permite organizarlo, validarlo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
$obj = json_decode($response);
var_dump( $obj);
```

**Consulta la info aqui:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: por ejemplo 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://queries.envia.com/provinces',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$obj = json_decode($response);
var_dump( $obj);
print $obj->name; // solo quiero los nombres de esta informacion pero me arroja el siguiente error Undefined property: stdClass::