# Recorrer un elemento json para acceder a su información

Tags: php, array, json, foreach

Hola amigos tengo este json en un archivo

```
{
    "Name": "Sin título2",
    "Description": "",
    "Date": "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 14:01:47 GMT",
    "UserID": "Manuel Dardón",
    "TotalTime": 26,
    "SlideCount": 4,
    "TakenSlide": 4,
    "TotalInteraction": 3,
    "TakenInteraction": 3,
    "Correct": 3,
    "Score": 3,
    "MaxScore": 3,
    "PassCondition": 0,
    "PassValue": 80,
    "Percent": 100,
    "Result": true,
    "Details": [
        {
            "SlideIndex": 2,
            "ReportID": "65_1",
            "Attempts": 1,
            "Score": 1,
            "MaxScore": 1,
            "Result": "Correcto",
            "Type": "True - False",
            "LearnerResponse": "65_4",
            "CorrectResponses": [
                "65_4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "SlideIndex": 3,
            "ReportID": "66_1",
            "Attempts": 1,
            "Score": 1,
            "MaxScore": 1,
            "Result": "Correcto",
            "Type": "Opción múltiple",
            "LearnerResponse": "66_4",
            "CorrectResponses": [
                "66_4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "SlideIndex": 4,
            "ReportID": "67_1",
            "Attempts": 1,
            "Score": 1,
            "MaxScore": 1,
            "Result": "Correcto",
            "Type": "Respuesta Múltiple",
            "LearnerResponse": "67_4[,]67_5[,]67_7",
            "CorrectResponses": [
                "67_4[,]67_5[,]67_7"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Cuando uso un foreach

```
    $file_json = 'report.json';
    $datosJson = file_get_contents($file_json);
    $datos = json_decode($datosJson, true);
    
    
    foreach($datos as $dato)
    {
        echo $channel[Name];
    }
```

Me muestra el mensaje de error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "Name"

Estoy seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal en el foreach pero no se bien que es, muchas gracias por la ayuda. No se si hago bien en convertir el json en un arreglo con el json_decode, también me imagino que si quiero ver lo que está en Details debo anidar otro foreach pero primero quiero ingresar a los primeros elementos. Saludos.

Comment: es un error de sintaxis... te pregunto en todos los nodos existe el indice name???

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. Para que no te pierdas con JSON debes tener claro que los arrays en JSON se representan por `[ ]`, y los objetos se representan po `{ }`, lo digo porque estás intentando leer el JSON global como un array, pero no lo es. El valor de `Name` está a nivel de objeto, no a nivel de array. Por ejemplo, `Details` sí apunta a un array, porque empieza por `[`. Entonces, si no es un array, no puedes leer dentro de un bucle. En el caso de `Name` accederías directamente desde el objeto, como veremos más adelante.
2. En cuanto al error, no puedes usar esta notación para leer claves de arrays: `$array[Clave]`, a no ser que estés dentro de un contexto de comillas dobles: `"echo $array[Clave]"`, si no estás en ese contexto, debes usar comillas: `$array['Clave']` o bien `$array["Clave"]`.
3. De todos modos, puedes usar `json_decode()` sin pasar `true`  como segundo parámetro, en ese caso tendrás un objeto y podrás leerlo con la notación `$objeto->propiedad`.

Dicho eso, el código debería funcionar así:

```
$datos = json_decode($datosJson);
echo $datos->Name;
```

**Salida:**

```
Sin título2
```

O, si por algún motivo lo quieres trabajar como array y no como objeto:

```
$datos = json_decode($datosJson, true);
echo $datos["Name"];
```

NÓTESE que en ningún caso usamos `foreach`, porque `Name` no se encuentra a nivel de array en el JSON.

Veamos el caso de `Details`, que sí se encuentra a nivel de array en el JSON:

```
foreach ($datos->Details as $item) {
    echo "Item: {$item->SlideIndex} Learner: {$item->LearnerResponse}".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Item: 2 Learner: 65_4
Item: 3 Learner: 66_4
Item: 4 Learner: 67_4[,]67_5[,]67_7
```

### Enlaces recomendados

- [Doctorado en JSON en 10 minutos :)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967) entendiendo esto tendrás a JSON en un bolsillo.
- Sobre el uso de comillas ver la pregunta: [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92944/29967)

Comment: Listo Muchas gracias, tienes razón te agradezco por la ayuda.

Comment: @ManuelDardón, ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!