# Como solucionar Error A JSONArray text must start with '['?

Tags: java

tengo un archivo json alojado en un servidor web con la siguiente informacion (Esta es una pequeña parte):

```
{"values":[{"first_name":"Alex","h_in":"77","h_meters":"1.96","last_name":"Acker"},{"first_name":"Hassan","h_in":"76","h_meters":"1.93","last_name":"Adams"},{"first_name":"Arron","h_in":"77","h_meters":"1.96","last_name":"Afflalo"},{"first_name":"Maurice","h_in":"77","h_meters":"1.96","last_name":"Ager"},{"first_name":"Alexis","h_in":"84","h_meters":"2.13","last_name":"Ajinca"},{"first_name":"LaMarcus","h_in":"83","h_meters":"2.11","last_name":"Aldridge"},
```

Por medio de un request estoy obteniendo esta información.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     HttpClient client =  HttpClient.newHttpClient();
     HttpRequest request = 
     HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://macheight.uc.r.appspot.com/")).build();
     client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
     .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
     .thenApply(Alturas::parse)
     .join();
}
```

Este es el error:  A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1].

```
public static String parse(String resposeBody){
JSONArray players = new JSONArray(resposeBody);
            for(int i=0;i < players.length();i++){
                JSONObject player = players.getJSONObject(i);
                String firtsName = player.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = player.getString("last_name");
                System.out.println(firtsName + " " + lastName);
            }
            return null;
}
```

Como podria solucionarlo? gracias de antemano.

Comment: Haz un print de `resposeBody` y te auto resuelves la pregunta. En caso de que no veas como hacerlo déjanos aquí un primer fragmento del resultado

Comment: Realizando solo un print del resposeBody ` {"values":[{"first_name":"Alex","h_in":"77","h_meters":"1.96","last_name":"Acker"},{"first_name":"Hassan","h_in":"76","h_meters":"1.93","last_name":"Adams"},` Imprime correctamente muchos datos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo obtener la suma total de una columna MySQL en un TextView de Android Studio con PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429418/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-la-suma-total-de-una-columna-mysql-en-un-textview-de-android-studi). En la respuesta dada trato de explicar de forma definitiva cómo analizar cualquier JSON para no tener ninguna dificultad en el futuro. El problema, también para tu caso, es **no entender del todo cómo se estructura JSON**.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas introducir el Json primero al `JSONObject()` ya que como te indica el error necesita un `[`:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resposeBody);
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("values");
...
```

El `JSONArray()` como su nombre indica, trabaja con Arrays y lo que le estas pasando es el objeto