# Cómo obtener los datos de un ajáx con jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un archivo ajáx.php que me genera un objeto con dos campos. Lo que quiero hacer es en otro archivo llamado funciones.js que uso jquery tomas esos valores de json y pasarlos a una variable.

Codigo del archivo ajax.php

```
$data['hora'] = $valor[0];
$data['ppm'] = $valor[1];
echo json_encode($data);
```

La salida muestra:
{"hora":"22:19","ppm":"125"}

yo lo que necesito es pasar esos dos datos a dos variables de jquery que estan en otro archivo .js

Lo que logre es lo siguiente:

```
function recogerDatos() {
           
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.open('GET','assets/js/mqtt/ajax.php',true);

            xhttp.send();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    datox = [];
                    datoy= [];
                    for(let item of datos){ 
                        datox= item['hora'];
                        datox= item['ppm'];
                    }
                }
            
            }
        }
        window.setTimeout(recogerDatos, 10000);
```

Pero me sale el giguiente error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (demo.js:130)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observo en tu planteamiento varios errores y términos mal empleados:

1. Estás diciendo que la respuesta es esta: `{"hora":"22:19","ppm":"125"}` Si es así, estamos ante un Objeto JSON, no ante un Array JSON, por tanto, no tiene ningún sentido intentar leer ese objeto dentro de un bucle, pues NO es un array.
2. Hablas de querer guardar los valores en dos variables, pero dichas variables las declaras como Arrays: `datox = []` y `datoy= []` ¿ ?

Asumiremos que tienes un entorno limpio en `ajax.php`. Por *limpio* se entiende que controlas las salidas en tu archivo y que la respuesta no viene mezclada con nada más que haría inválido el JSON. Si es así, solamente tines que hacer esto:

```
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                let datox = datos.hora;
                let datoy = datos.ppm;
            }
```

Veamos un ejemplo asumiendo la respuesta a mano aquí:

```js
let responseText='{"hora":"22:19","ppm":"125"}';
let datos=JSON.parse(responseText);
let datox = datos.hora;
let datoy = datos.ppm;
console.log(`datox = ${datox} y datoy = ${datoy}`);
```

Como ves, funciona, si en tu caso no funciona, revisa las salidas en tu archivo PHP y verifica que no sale nada por pantalla aparte de la respuesta:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

### Recomendaciones

- Si te interesa tener un doctorado en JSON, te invito a leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967). Si entiendes lo planteado en ella, no tendrás ningún problema con ningún JSON, por complejo que éste sea. Son diez minutos de lectura que te ahorrarán muchas horas / días / semanas en el futuro.

Comment: A.Cenado Muchas gracias por la ayuda e entendido y como lo nombre al inicio de la consulta dije que era un objeto la salida, lo que nunca me di cuenta es que esa variables del objeto las quería almacenar en un arreglo. Probe su codigo y me tiro este error.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (demo.js:131)

Lo que pude observar es que el responseText lo devuelve vacio

Comment: Si te devuelve el `responseText` vacío puede que haya en problema en el archivo `.php` , ¿hiciste algún cambio en ese archivo?

Comment: te agregue una repuesta porque era muy larga.

Answer (score 0):

No no realice ningun cambio es mas este es mi codigo en aja por el cual le paso la variable al php para realizar una consulta en mysql y cuando realizo el **console.log(response)** dentro del si todo salio bien en la salida veo todos los resultados. @A. Cedano

```
 action = "grafica";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/js/mqtt/ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            data:{action:action,seleccion:seleccion},
            success:function(response){
                //console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Demo.js

```
demo = {


initDocChart: function() {
    chartColor = "#FFFFFF";

    // General configuration for the charts with Line gradientStroke
    gradientChartOptionsConfiguration = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        exportEnabled: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            bodySpacing: 4,
            mode: "nearest",
            intersect: 0,
            position: "nearest",
            xPadding: 10,
            yPadding: 10,
            caretPadding: 10
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: 0,
                gridLines: 0,
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                },
                gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                    drawTicks: false,
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                display: 0,
                gridLines: 0,
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                },
                gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                    drawTicks: false,
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }]
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 15,
                bottom: 15
            }
        }
    };
},

initDashboardPageCharts: function() {

    gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },

        tooltips: {
            backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
            titleFontColor: '#333',
            bodyFontColor: '#666',
            bodySpacing: 4,
            xPadding: 12,
            mode: "nearest",
            intersect: 0,
            position: "nearest"
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 1.6,
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                    color: 'rgba(29,140,248,0.0)',
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                },
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 60,
                    suggestedMax: 125,
                    padding: 20,
                    fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
                }
            }],

            xAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 1.6,
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                    color: 'rgba(225,78,202,0.1)',
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                },
                ticks: {
                    padding: 20,
                    fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
                }
            }]
        }
    };

    //****************************************************
    //* aqui van los datos para la grafica del dashboard *
    //***************************************************
        
        function recogerDatos() {
           
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.open('GET','assets/js/mqtt/ajax.php',true);

            xhttp.send();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    let datox = datos.hora;
                    let datoy = datos.ppm;
                    console.log(`datox = ${datox} y datoy = ${datoy}`);

                }
            
            }
        }
        window.setTimeout(recogerDatos, 10000);
    
    var datoy=[];
    var datox=[];
   //setInterval(function() {
        for(var i=0;i<=120;i++){
            datoy[i]= Math.floor((Math.random() * (1200 - 300 + 1)) + 300);
            datox[i]= i;
        }
    //console.log(datoy);
    //}, 3000);
    

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartLinePurple").getContext("2d");

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.2)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors

    var data = {
        labels: datox,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Data",
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
            borderColor: '#d048b6',
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            pointBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
            pointBorderWidth: 20,
            pointHoverRadius: 4,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
            pointRadius: 4,
            data: datoy,
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    });
},
```

};

Luego la llamo desde funciones.js dependiendo que selecciono

```
$("select[name=dispositivo]").change(function() {
        seleccion = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        console.log("Has seleccionado - " + seleccion);
        //pasamos los datos a ajax para mostrar la grafica
        action = "grafica";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/js/mqtt/ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            data:{action:action,seleccion:seleccion},
            success:function(response){
                //console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        }); });
```

Comment: Si dices que ves los datos en el console.log no entiendo entonces cuál es el problema ¿? Por otra parte no uses el área de respuestas para aclaraciones, puedes editar la pregunta para ello.

Comment: Claro pero el codigo de ajax lo tengo en un archivo funciones.js que pasa la variable por metodo get a ajax.php para realizar una consulta a bases de mysql para luego devolver en formato Json (Objeto) a otro archivo demo.js para tomar esos valores y manipularlos desde ahi. Que desde el demo.js el responseText lo recive vacio. y nose porque si la consulta que hago en el funciones.js con ajax esta lleno el console.log(response).

Comment: Es que la respuesta tienes que recibirla en el mismo archivo .js que hace la petición Ajax, o sea, en funciones.js, ¿por qué quieres leerla la respuesta en un archivo que no ha sido el que ha hecho la petición? Eso no funciona así ni tiene sentido tampoco.

Comment: porque me gusta separar los archivos según se el contenido por ejemplo en el funciones.js analizo las acciones que hago con un select depende lo que selecciono es la búsqueda que realizo en mysql y en el demo.js tengo la programación de una gráfica, quiero recibir esos datos para gratificarlos.

Comment: Entiendo que quieras separar los archivos lo cual es una buena práctica. Pero lo propio sería llamar desde funciones.js al archivo demo.js y poner en este último la petición Ajax completa. Uno de los motivos para hacer esto es que Ajax es asíncrono y por tanto es mejor manejar las respuestas en el mismo archivo que hace la petición, no en otro archivo, eso no tiene sentido para fines de simplificación/organización del código. Puedes hacerlo como pretendes, si quieres, pero eso no te ayudará a organizar mejor tu código, al contrario.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista, pero existe la posibilidad de poder lograrlo?

Comment: ¿Lograr qué cosa?

Comment: Logra leer los datos desde demo,js sin la necesidad de llamarlo desde otro archivo lo que pasa si pondo el codigo de demo.js en funciones.js me quedaria un codigo de muchas lineas nose me da a cosa quisas es un problema visual mio.

Comment: Si tú quieres poder manejar la respuesta de Ajax (hecha desde `funciones.js`) en otro archivo (`demo.js`). Tendrás que incluir `demo.js` en `funciones.js`, crear una función en `demo.js` y pasar la respuesta de Ajax a esa función. Supongamos que la función se llama `function manejarRespuesta(losDatos) { /*Aqui trabajar losDatos*/ }`  y en la parte `success` de Ajax pasarías los datos a esa función: `success:function(response){ manejarRespuesta(response); },` Es lo que te decía antes, que es más lío organizar así el código.

Comment: Entonces tu me recomiendas que vuelque el codigo de demo,js  en fuinciones dentro de la parte success de ajax.

Comment: Yo no sé lo que tienes en `demo.js` ni cuál es el propósito de ese archivo... al menos para este caso, puedes tomar el bloque de código donde pretendes manejar la respuesta de Ajax y crear una función en `funciones.js` y llamar a esa función desde el `success` ... Ahora bien si en `funciones.js` tienes más casos así (donde se le pasan datos a otras partes de `demo.js`) podrías pensar en fusionar ambos archivos, creando uno solo. Son sugerencias, luego sobre la marcha deberás ver qué es mejor, pues no conozco tu contexto, si usas CMS como Wordpress, etc, para poder decirte lo que sea mejor.

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta anterior para que veas que tiene demo.js ese es una libreria de chartjs y te puse como la llamo desde funciones

Comment: No entiendo mucho ... Lo que me interesa saber es cómo relacionas `funciones.js` y   `demos.js`  ¿podrías indicar con claridad como haces esa relación?