# Cómo obtener valores de los registros incluidos en un JSONObject que está en la posición 0 de un JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bucle-for, bucles

En mi código en Android Studio, al realizar una consulta a una base de datos mySQL mediante Volley y un archivo PHP la información del resultado de la consulta es recibida como un JSONObject en la posición [0] de un JSONArray.

He intentado acceder a los valores de cada registro contenido en ese JSONObject mediante un bucle FOR pero no lo consigo, el bucle toma siempre los valores del primer registro en cada iteración.
**¿Alguien sabe cómo sacar los valores de todos los registros incluidos en ese JSONObject?**

He encontrado preguntas parecidas en el foro pero son arrays que tienen headers para poder acceder a los registros, pero en mi caso los registros no tienen header. También he encontrado preguntas de Arrays en JSONArrays, pero en mi caso es un JSONObject en un JSONArray.

Éste sería un ejemplo del JSONArray, que contiene en la posición 0 un JSONObject con los registros obtenidos de la consulta a la base de datos mySQL (he separado los registros con un salto de línea para que se vean mejor).

```
[{"ID_PLAYER":"40","NOM_JUG":"ewin","VIRT_DATE":"2000-01-01","ACCOUNT_MONEY":"0.0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND":"1","BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED":"1","CURRENT_PACK":"Europe-Country-Capital","CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL":"1","TOKEN_X2":"4","TOKEN_X3":"2","LOTTERY_TICKETS":"3.0","CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE":"Living with parents","TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE":"0.0","MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF":"1","RANDOM_MARKET":"1","AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN":"0","TEXT_EDITOR_QUE":"ewin","TEXT_EDITOR_ANS":"ewin","ID_QUESTION":"0","COINS":"1000","userPlayer":"User","passwordPlayer":"Password"},

{"ID_PLAYER":"41","NOM_JUG":"Rick","VIRT_DATE":"2000-01-01","ACCOUNT_MONEY":"0.0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND":"1","BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED":"1","CURRENT_PACK":"Europe-Country-Capital","CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL":"1","TOKEN_X2":"4","TOKEN_X3":"2","LOTTERY_TICKETS":"3.0","CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE":"Living with parents","TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE":"0.0","MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF":"1","RANDOM_MARKET":"1","AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN":"0","TEXT_EDITOR_QUE":"Rick","TEXT_EDITOR_ANS":"Rick","ID_QUESTION":"0","COINS":"1000","userPlayer":"User","passwordPlayer":"Password"}]
```

EDITO: Tras las modificaciones realizadas en el PHP el JSON resultante tiene este formato:

```
{"datos":[{"NOM_JUG":"Laura","VIRT_DATE":"2000-01-01","ACCOUNT_MONEY":"0.0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND":"1","BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED":"1","CURRENT_PACK":"Europe-Country-Capital","CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL":"1","TOKEN_X2":"4","TOKEN_X3":"2","LOTTERY_TICKETS":"3.0","CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE":"Living with parents","TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE":"0.0","MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF":"1","RANDOM_MARKET":"1","AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN":"0","TEXT_EDITOR_QUE":"Laura","TEXT_EDITOR_ANS":"Laura","ID_QUESTION":"0","COINS":"1000"},{"NOM_JUG":"Antonio","VIRT_DATE":"2000-01-01","ACCOUNT_MONEY":"0.0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND":"1","BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED":"1","CURRENT_PACK":"Europe-Country-Capital","CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL":"1","TOKEN_X2":"4","TOKEN_X3":"2","LOTTERY_TICKETS":"3.0","CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE":"Living with parents","TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE":"0.0","MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF":"1","RANDOM_MARKET":"1","AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN":"0","TEXT_EDITOR_QUE":"Antonio","TEXT_EDITOR_ANS":"Antonio","ID_QUESTION":"0","COINS":"1000"}]}
```

Éste es el código que estoy utilizando para intentar acceder a los valores de cada registro *EDITO:tras adaptarlo a la respuesta de @A.Cedano:

```
private void llamadovolley5(){

        final String userPlayer = etUser.getText().toString();
        final String passwordPlayer = etPassword.getText().toString();
        String url = "http://192.168.1.129/studyBonusGame/3CheckUserNew.php";

        // POST parameters
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("userPlayer", userPlayer);
        params.put("passwordPlayer", passwordPlayer);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {
Log.d("XYZ",response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONArray datos=response.getJSONArray("datos");
                            for (int i=0; i < datos.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject item = datos.getJSONObject(i);

                                ObjectPlayer player = new ObjectPlayer();

                                player.setPlayerName((item.getString("NOM_JUG")));
                                player.setPlayerVirtualDate(item.getString("VIRT_DATE"));
                                player.setAccountMoney(item.getDouble("ACCOUNT_MONEY"));
                                player.setWeekTournamentMode(item.getInt("WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE"));
                                player.setWeekTournamentRound(item.getInt("WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND"));
                                player.setButtonFinancesEnabled(item.getInt("BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED"));
                                player.setButtonQAManagerEnabled(item.getInt("BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED"));
                                player.setButtonSuccessErrorGameEnabled(item.getInt("BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED"));
                                player.setCurrentPack(item.getString("CURRENT_PACK"));
                                player.setCorrectQueVirtualDate(item.getInt("CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE"));
                                player.setWeekTournamentLevel(item.getInt("WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL"));
                                player.setTokenX2(item.getInt("TOKEN_X2"));
                                player.setTokenX3(item.getInt("TOKEN_X3"));
                                player.setLotteryTickets(item.getDouble("LOTTERY_TICKETS"));
                                player.setCurrentLivingPlace(item.getString("CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE"));
                                player.setTotalLifeScore(item.getDouble("TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE"));
                                player.setMusicMenusOnOff(item.getInt("MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF"));
                                player.setRandomMarket(item.getInt("RANDOM_MARKET"));
                                player.setAfterPacksScreen(item.getInt("AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN"));
                                player.setTextEditorQue(item.getString("TEXT_EDITOR_QUE"));
                                player.setTextEditorAns(item.getString("TEXT_EDITOR_ANS"));
                                player.setIdQuestion(item.getInt("ID_QUESTION"));
                                player.setCoins(item.getInt("COINS"));

                                d.importOnlinePlayersTable(player);
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(userPass2Activity.this, "Imported correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rq.add(jsonObjRequest);
    }
```

Código PHP con el que realizo la consulto a mySQL:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

try{

      $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database" , "root", "");
      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql="SELECT NOM_JUG, VIRT_DATE, ACCOUNT_MONEY, WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE, WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND, BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED, BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED, BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED, CURRENT_PACK, CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE, WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL, TOKEN_X2, TOKEN_X3, LOTTERY_TICKETS, CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE, TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE, MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF, RANDOM_MARKET, AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN, TEXT_EDITOR_QUE, TEXT_EDITOR_ANS, ID_QUESTION, COINS FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer= :userPlayer AND passwordPlayer= :passwordPlayer";

      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

      //$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

      $userPlayer  = $_POST['userPlayer'];
      $passwordPlayer   = $_POST['passwordPlayer'];

      //$userPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($content['userPlayer']));
      $userPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($userPlayer));
      $passwordPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($passwordPlayer));

      $resultado->bindValue(":userPlayer", $userPlayer);
      $resultado->bindValue(":passwordPlayer", $passwordPlayer);

      $resultado->execute();


      $res=array();
      while( $row = $resultado -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          $res[]=$row;
      }
      //header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo json_encode( array("datos"=>$res) );
      exit();   



      /*$res = $resultado -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $json = json_encode($res);

      echo $json;*/


}catch(Exception $e){
      echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage()));
      exit();
}

?>
```

EDITO: Incluye el resultado de ejecutar el archivo PHP en el navegador.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "userPlayer" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\studyBonusGame\3CheckUserNew.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "passwordPlayer" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\studyBonusGame\3CheckUserNew.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
{"datos":[{"NOM_JUG":"Laura","VIRT_DATE":"2000-01-01","ACCOUNT_MONEY":"0.0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND":"1","BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED":"1","CURRENT_PACK":"Europe-Country-Capital","CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL":"1","TOKEN_X2":"4","TOKEN_X3":"2","LOTTERY_TICKETS":"3.0","CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE":"Living with parents","TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE":"0.0","MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF":"1","RANDOM_MARKET":"1","AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN":"0","TEXT_EDITOR_QUE":"Laura","TEXT_EDITOR_ANS":"Laura","ID_QUESTION":"0","COINS":"1000"},{"NOM_JUG":"Yulimoji","VIRT_DATE":"2000-01-01","ACCOUNT_MONEY":"0.0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE":"0","WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND":"1","BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED":"1","BUTTON_SUC...**continua así hasta mostrar todos los registros de la base de datos**
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Un `JSONArray` estará delimitado por esto: `[ ]` y un `JSONObject` está delimitado por esto: `{ }`, luego, uno puede contener a otro, no hay problema. Si es un array, puedes acceder directamente, usando el índice, o a cada uno de los elementos usando un bucle. Si tú quieres solamente el primer elemento, entonces búscalo en el índice `0`  y luego léelo según la estructura que tenga, o, mejor aún, lo puedes mapear a un POJO usando Gson, como te sugiere @JordiTurell, lo cual es una maravilla. De todos modos, ¿por qué si necesitas sólo 1 objeto obtienes más de uno?

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por responder. Eso es, tengo un JSONArray que contiene un JSONObject donde está toda la información. Accedo a ese JSONObject en el índice 0, pero es justo ahí donde tengo el problema, no sé cómo leer los valores de cada registro que hay en ese JSONObject. Estoy investigando sobre Gson tal como me habéis recomendado para intentar dar con una solución. Sobre tu pregunta, no estoy seguro a qué te refieres. El JSONArray que contiene el JSONObject, que a su vez contiene los resultados de la consulta a mySQL lo obtengo de esa forma xq es la única q he conseguido q funcione.

Comment: Para obtener el valor de una propiedad debes usar uno de los métodos `get` de la clase `JSONObject`, según sea el tipo de dato de cada propiedad. Una de las grandes ventajas de usar Gson es que el JSON puede mapearse a un POJO, y luego usas esa instancia del POJO para mostrar los datos. Imagina que necesitas mostrar toda la info del JSON y creas en el POJO un método `getAll()` que te muestra toda la información... pues con una sola línea de código estarías mostrando todo, sin necesidad de hacerlo uno por uno. Mi pregunta se refiere a que si necesitas un solo JSON, no varios ...

Comment: ... por qué no traes ese solo JSON. El hecho es que estás transportando datos (con el coste que ello implica) para luego desechar parte de esos datos. No es una muy buena práctica, lo único que justificaría eso es que los otros datos que aquí no usas, los uses en otra parte de este mismo contexto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por ayudarme. Me cuesta seguirte, mi nivel es todavía bajo, pero tus comentarios me sirven para descubrir nuevas líneas para seguir aprendiendo. Tengo la sensación de que mi problema es más simple que todo eso. Creo que el error está en la forma en que he conseguido enviar el resultado de la consulta mySQL desde el PHP a mi código android. Estoy seguro que debe haber una manera de enviar el resultado como un simple JSONArray que se pueda recorrer con un bucle para extraer la información. Pero no lo he conseguido...

Comment: ...Lo mejor que he podido conseguir es enviar el resultado como un JSONArray, pero...(aquí está el problema)...el JSONArray contiene toda la información en la posición 0, ya sea el resultado de la consulta 1 registro o 1000 registros de la base de datos mySQL, todos están en la posición 0 del array. Intento utilizar un FOR para sacar los valores mediante los GET, pero m falta algo más para poder recorrer cada registro de esa posición 0, y no tengo los conocimientos necesarios para averiguar qué me hace falta. Voy a añadir el PHP a la pregunta en caso de que sirva d ayuda para explicarme mejor.

Comment: Entiendo, poco a poco irás aprendiendo. Volley te da la posibilidad de tres tipos de respuesta: `String`, `JSONArray` o `JSONObject`, según lo que necesites tú puedes: 1. En el servidor crear el objeto como lo necesites; 2. En Android, indicar el tipo según lo que devuelva el servidor. Mi pregunta es si para este caso la consulta SQL debe devolver una sola fila ¿? por tus comentarios parece que sí. Si es así, entonces ponle un `LIMIT 1` a la consulta SQL, obtén los datos con `fetch`, no con `fetchAll` y emite los datos como un JSONObject. Lo que debe quedar claro aquí es que no tienes que ...

Comment: ... plegarte a una determinada organización de los datos (`JSONArray` sí o sí), sino que debes adaptar la respuesta a lo que necesites, indicando en Volley el tipo de dato que obtendrás en esa petición. Y es que JSON es una forma de organizar datos, y tú estructuras esos datos como mejor te convenga, según cada caso, no tienes por qué ceñirte a un modelo fijo.

Comment: Cuando puedas, [lee esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967) donde yo he explicado en qué consiste JSON. Si entiendes eso, no tendrás ningún problema con ningún JSON, por complejo que sea. Y sabiendo que Volley también es flexible, comprenderás que puedes perfectamente en cada caso estructurar tu respuesta de servidor de la forma que sea más simple para consumir. En algunos casos necesitarás un JSONArray, en otros un JSONObject y en muchos casos habrá de uno y de otro en una misma respuesta. Poco importa la complejidad, si entiendes lo fundamental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentaré dar una respuesta a tu problema.

Te recomiendo que no transportes nunca datos que no vas a necesitar. Esto supondría consumo de recursos de forma innecesaria.

Si necesitas **un solo objeto** puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Poner un `LIMIT 1` a la consulta SQL para te traiga la única fila que necesitas
2. Usar `fetch`, no `fetchAll` al obtener los datos. Este último, efectivamente, te meterá los datos dentro de un array con un índice `0`, aunque sea una sola fila.

---

> #### NOTA IMPORTANTE:
>
> En la depuración se reveló que el servidor no estaba recibiendo los
> datos en la superglobal `$_POST`, sino en el flujo de entrada. Si eso
> ocurre, entonces en vez de recurrir a `$_POST` para obtener los datos
> que son pasados, se puede hacer de este modo:
>
> ```
> $content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
>
> $userPlayer = $content['userPlayer'];
> $passwordPlayer = $content['passwordPlayer'];
> ```
>
> También, cuando se espera del servidor una respuesta JSON, conviene
> controlar cuidadosamente el flujo del código en el servidor, previendo
> además en todos los casos los posibles errores y creando un array con
> una clave `error` asociada a un mensaje apropiado. Esta práctica
> facilitará que la respuesta sea incorporada a una política de manejo
> de errores en la App, de modo que el usuario no se quede en el limbo
> ante posibles errores. Ejemplo de cosas que deberían controlarse en
> este caso: que variables esenciales para la consulta no estén vacías,
> que la consulta arroje datos, etc.

---

Aplicando esto el código en PHP quedaría así:

```
/*
   *Conviene poner un header con el tipo de dato y la codificación
*/
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

try{

      $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database" , "root", "");
      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql="SELECT * FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer= :userPlayer AND passwordPlayer= :passwordPlayer LIMIT 1";

      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

      /*
         Hágase lo dicho en la NOTA más arriba
         si los datos no están en $_POST
      */
      $userPlayer  = $_POST['userPlayer'];
      $passwordPlayer   = $_POST['passwordPlayer'];


      $userPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($userPlayer));
      $passwordPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($passwordPlayer));

      $resultado->bindValue(":userPlayer", $userPlayer);
      $resultado->bindValue(":passwordPlayer", $passwordPlayer);

      $resultado->execute();

      $res = $resultado -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      echo json_encode($res);
      exit();   

}catch(Exception $e){
      /*
         *OJO a esto. Si el cliente (Android) espera un JSON
         *debes emitir un JSON también en los casos de error
         *Además esto te sirve para controla, como veremos en el código de Android
         *En producción, evita mostrar errores internos
         *cambia getMessage por un error personalizado
      */
      echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage());
      exit();
}
```

El código anterior, te emitirá un `JSONObject` en el contexto de Java, con esta estructura más o menos:

```
{
    "columna1" : "valor1",
    "columna2" : "valor2"
}
```

En caso de error, devolverá esto:

```
{
    "error" : "El mensaje de error"
}
```

Cuando hagas el [doctorado en JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967), comprenderás que en ambos casos esta petición devuelve un `JSONObject`, por tanto, desde Android podrías decirle a Volley que necesitas un `JSONObjectRequest`:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, TU_URL, null,
        response -> {
            try {
                /*
                   *Aquí tienes los datos en response
                   *No hay que convertir nada, ya lo obtienes como JSONObject
                   *Ahora, 1º verifica que el servidor no respondió con una clave "error"
                   *O sea, el catch que hay en PHP
                 */
                if response.containsKey("error") {
                   /*
                      *Manejar esta situación de error
                      *Otra situación que se puede manejar aquí es si la consulta no encuentra datos
                      *Eso por cierto no lo estás contemplando en PHP
                    */
                 } else {
                    /*
                       *Leer los datos, aquí si usas Gson
                       *puedes mapear los datos
                       *o puedes crear una clase envoltorio que comprenda Pojo y Error juntos
                       *Mostramos cómo se leería el valor de la columna1
                       *No hay conversiones, ni hay bucles, porque es un JSONObject
                    */
                    System.out.println(response.getString("columna1"));
                     
                  
                 }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                /*Tratar error o mostrar un mensaje*/
            }
        },
        error -> {
            /*Tratar error o mostrar un mensaje*/
        }
);
```

---

Si necesitas **varios objetos** puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Quitar el `LIMIT 1` a la consulta SQL para te traiga la todas las filas que necesitas
2. Puedes seguir usando `fetch`, no `fetchAll` al obtener los datos, sólo que leerás cada fila en `while` (PHP recomienda evitar `fetchAll` si se esperan muchas filas, pues puede haber problemas de memoria.

Aplicando esto el código en PHP quedaría así:

```
/*
   *Conviene poner un header con el tipo de dato y la codificación
*/
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

try{

      $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database" , "root", "");
      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql="SELECT * FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer= :userPlayer AND passwordPlayer= :passwordPlayer";

      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

      /*
         Hágase lo dicho en la NOTA más arriba
         si los datos no están en $_POST
      */
      $userPlayer  = $_POST['userPlayer'];
      $passwordPlayer   = $_POST['passwordPlayer'];


      $userPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($userPlayer));
      $passwordPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($passwordPlayer));

      $resultado->bindValue(":userPlayer", $userPlayer);
      $resultado->bindValue(":passwordPlayer", $passwordPlayer);

      $resultado->execute();

      $res=array();
      while( $row = $resultado -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          $res[]=$row;
      }
      echo json_encode( array("datos"=>$res) );
      exit();   

}catch(Exception $e){
      /*
         *OJO a esto. Si el cliente (Android) espera un JSON
         *debes emitir un JSON también en los casos de error
         *Además esto te sirve para controla, como veremos en el código de Android
         *En producción, evita mostrar errores internos
         *cambia getMessage por un error personalizado
      */
      echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage());
      exit();
}
```

El código anterior te emitirá un `JSONObject` en el contexto de Java. Aquí he recurrido a un truco **por conveniencia**.

Dado que la posibilidad de error se maneja con un JSONObject, para guardar uniformidad con Volley (que pedirá un JSONObject), he metido el `JSONArray` con los datos dentro de una clave `data`. Así, la respuesta, en caso de haber datos, estará siempre en un JSONObject, pero los datos en un `JSONArray`. No hay pánico con esto, veremos en el código Android cómo se lee y así aprendemos que es el código el que se adapta a nuestras necesidades, no nosotros al código.

La respuesta, en caso de datos, quedaría así (insisto en que vuelvas a leer [la respuesta del *doctorado* en JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967), hasta que ninguna estructura JSON te haga caer en pánico):

```
{
  "datos":[
    {
      "columna1":"valorA",
      "columna2":"valorB"
    },
    {
      "columna1":"valorX",
      "columna2":"valorY"
    }
  ]
}
```

En caso de error, devolverá esto:

```
{
    "error" : "El mensaje de error"
}
```

Como ya se dijo, en ambos casos esta petición devuelve un `JSONObject`, por tanto, desde Android podrías seguirle diciendo a Volley que necesitas un `JSONObjectRequest` (en los casos en que necesites un array, le indicarás que quieres un `JSONArrayRequest`, pero es el caso aquí):

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, TU_URL, null,
        response -> {
            try {
                /*
                   *Aquí tienes los datos en response
                   *No hay que convertir nada, ya lo obtienes como JSONObject
                   *Ahora, 1º verifica que el servidor no respondió con una clave "error"
                   *O sea, el catch que hay en PHP
                 */
                if response.containsKey("error") {
                   /*
                      *Manejar esta situación de error
                      *Otra situación que se puede manejar aquí es si la consulta no encuentra datos
                      *Eso por cierto no lo estás contemplando en PHP
                    */
                 } else {
                    /*
                       *Leer los datos, aquí si usas Gson
                       *puedes mapear los datos
                       *o puedes crear una clase envoltorio que comprenda Pojo y Error juntos
                       * -----------------------------
                       *OJO aquí. Antes dijimos que los datos en sí mismos venían en un array
                       *pero dicho array está en la clave "datos"
                       *entonces obtendremos ese JSONArray y lo recorreremos
                    */
                    JSONArray datos=response.getJSONArray("datos");
                    for (int i=0; i < datos.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject item=datos.getJSONObject(i);
                        System.out.(item.getString("columna1"));
                     }
                                          
                 }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                /*Tratar error o mostrar un mensaje*/
            }
        },
        error -> {
            /*Tratar error o mostrar un mensaje*/
        }
);
```

#### En conclusión

Tanto desde PHP como desde Android, tú puedes adaptar el código (tipo de petición, tipo de respuesta y lectura de esa respuesta), según te convenga. Teniendo en cuenta siempre aspectos como manejo de errores, no solamente errores de red, sino también de lógica, como errores de conexión, o consultas que no devuelven datos... todos esos aspectos deberían ser cubiertos.

Espero que esta respuesta ayude a comprender mejor, y si hay alguna duda puedes preguntar en comentarios.

Comment: Antes siquiera de probar lo explicado en tu respuesta quería agradecerte mucho que hayas dedicado tu esfuerzo para elaborar una respuesta tan bien explicada y tan completa. Ojalá hubiera más gente así por el mundo. He leído la respuesta del doctorado en JSON (muy buena) y he intentando adaptar mi código a tu explicación, sin embargo ahora el problema es que la app arroja el error  `com.android.volley.ParseError:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be coverted to JSONObject` y por más que lo intento no consigo solucionarlo. He actualizado el código de mi pregunta...

Comment: ...para mostrar la adaptación que he intentado realizar gracias a tu respuesta.

Comment: @Javierungo eso ocurre porque estás recibiendo una cadena desde el servidor, quizá el código está entrando en la parte del error ¿?  Esa parte no la adaptaste a JSON, debes ponerla así: `echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage());
      exit();` como he explicado en la respuesta. Si sigue sin funcionar, haz un `Log` de `response`  poniendo esto: `Log.d("XYZ",response.toString());`y dinos qué muestra revisando el Logcat.

Comment: Te agradezco de nuevo la ayuda que me estás prestando. Me está ayudando a superar este bache en el camino y a mejorar en mi proceso de aprendizaje. He modificado el PHP, tenías razón, cuando lo revisé no noté los cambios en esa línea y no la modifiqué...

Comment: Aún con esa modificación el error que comentaba antes sigue apareciendo cuando el código intenta leer la response y se muestra en el toast `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` del Response.ErrorListener. No he podido hacer Log de la response porque el error se produce antes de que el código acceda a la response.

Comment: Yo no hablo del Toast, @Javierungo. La forma de depurar en Android Studio es con `Log`, por ejemplo, si tú pones: `Log.d("XYZ",response.toString());` podrás ver en el Logcat, lo que está respondiendo el servidor. Conviene que sepas eso, pues te ayudará muchísimo a depurar tu código. El **`Logcat`** es una opción que aparece en la parte inferior de Android Studio, si haces clic ahí, se abrirá una ventana con los mensajes que imprimiste durante el código con `Log.` Como dije antes, pon `Log.d("XYZ",response.toString());` dentro del `OnResponse`, luego revisa el Logcat y me dices lo que imprime.

Comment: A eso me refería, he intentado imprimir en el Logcat la response mediante la línea `Log.d("XYZ",response.toString());` dentro del OnResponse, pero no imprime nada porque el error se produce antes de tener la response. El programa no llega a entrar en el OnResponse, salta directamente al Response.ErrorListener

Comment: @Javierungo anteriormente dijiste que la App arrojaba este error: `com.android.volley.ParseError:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be coverted to JSONObject` ¿dónde viste ese error? Eso suele ocurrir porque desde el servidor está saliendo por pantalla más cosas aparte del JSON que debe responder, con los datos o con el error. ¿Puedes poner el PHP completo como lo tienes ahora, para revisar si tienes alguna salida por pantalla aparte del JSON?

Comment: Ese error aparece en el toast que está en el método  `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)`. En el enunciado de la pregunta están actualmente tanto el código del PHP como el del método de android, exactamente como los tengo ahora y arrojando el error del que estamos hablando, que se produce cuando se ejecuta el método `llamadovolley5` de la app. Reitero las gracias por la ayuda que me estás ofreciendo, se agradece y mucho.

Comment: @Javierungo ¿confirmas que **todo** lo que hay en el archivo PHP que estás poniendo como URL de la petición Volley es lo que aparece arriba en la pregunta? ¿Seguro que no hay nada más en tu archivo PHP?  Ese mensaje de error ocurre porque desde el servidor está saliendo algo más, aparte del JSON y a veces es por una simpleza, como un `echo` o un bloque HTML o un mensaje de error interno. ¿Puedes probar esa URL en un navegador, pasándole los parámetros que le estuvieras pasando en la petición exactamente igual? Si hay error los verás en la pantalla del navegador.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133260/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-javierungo).

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Javierungo te lo voi a explicar como lo hago yo. Lo primero de todo creo una clase que sera el objeto tal cual del JSON que voi a recivir. Tiene que ser igual con las claves sensitives. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Response{
{
 private String ID_PLAYER;
 private String NOM_JUG;
 private String VIRT_DATE;
 private String ACCOUNT_MONEY;
 private String WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE;
 private String WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND;
 private String BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED;
 private String BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED;
 .... Asi con cada propiedad

 //Una vez creado todas las propiedades creamos el constructor
 public Response(String ID_PLAYER, String NOM_JUG ...){
    this.ID_PLAYER = ID_PLAYER;
    this.NOM_JUG = NOM_JUG;
    .... Asi con cada propiedad
 }

 //Despues tenemos que crear los sets y gets de cada propiedad
 public String getIDPlayer(){ return ID_PLAYER; }
 public void setIDPlayer(String idplayer){ this.ID_PLAYER = idplayer; }
 .... Asi con cada propiedad
}
```

Una vez echo de esta manera tenemos que tener la libreria de Gson para serelizar y deserializar.

Para deserializar que es lo que quieres tu es lo siguiente:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type ListResponse = new TypeToke<ArrayList<Response>>() {}.getType();
List<Response> response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ListResponse);
```

Para sereliarizar seria:

```
Gson gson = ne Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(Response) //aqui le pongo el objeto tal cual pero le puedes meter una lista.
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy intentar adaptar lo que comentas a mi código a ver si lo consigo. La verdad que es una nueva línea que no había seguido todavía. Pensaba que la solución estaría más relacionada con la modificación del bucle FOR para extraer los valores de cada registro del JSONObject.