# ¿Como puedo hacer para que en un txt o Json que guarda una lista de usuarios guarde tambien los animales de cada uno? (Se entiende mejor con contexto)

Tags: java, txt, gson

Estoy atrapado con esto y agradeceria mucho su ayuda. Se trata de un juego de combates de animales (por consola)

Tengo una clase Usuario y una Animal.

Los atributos de un usuario son: nombre, id, contraseña

Los atributos de un animal son: nombre, vida, ataque1, ataque2

Ya tengo implementadas las clases y métodos necesarios para iniciar sesión con id y contraseña, estos usuarios se guardan en un txt, una linea por cada usuario y los atributos de nombre, id y contraseña separador por ;

nombreUsuario;123456789;password
nombreUsuario2;987654321;password

MI PROBLEMA: El usuario debe poder ir agregando por ejemplo en un arraylist, los animales que va consiguiendo al ganar un combate. ¿Pero como llevar eso a mi txt?

Los animales disponibles son 10 y uno de estos, perro por ejemplo. Tiene las mismas caractericasticas para todos los jugadores, el perro de jugador1 tiene 30 de vida, el de jugador2 tambien 30. No es editable, son genéricos. Y se encuentran todos en un .txt de la siguiente forma:

perro;50;4;3
gato;35;5;4etc

En donde estudio me sugirieron que en el txt de animales, a cada animal le pusiera un id, asi cada usuario podria tener un arraylist de id´s de animales y cuando escribiera estos usuarios en el txt solo se guardarian los id's (parecido funcionan las bases de datos me dijeron, pero no conozco nada de base datos). Algo así

nombreUsuario;123456789;password;1;2;5

nombreUsuario2;987654321;password;4;2;6;8;9 los numeros despues de contraseña sonids

El problema de esta solucion es que no tengo idea como hacer para que cuando convierta mi txt a usuarios (objetos java) pueda ocupar estos id's para que se conviertan de alguna forma en una lista de animales que tiene el usuario y no solo numeros sin ningun significado

Agradecería mucho su ayuda de como implementar esto ya sea en en txt o Json, me es mas complicado aprender Json (tengo una nocion por videos con json simple y Gson pero mientras sea una solucion a lo que describo arriba me salvaria :(

PD: No se nada de base de datos como dije, por lo que aprender a usar una se escapa de mi dominio para lo que he visto de progra en el ramo que estoy dando y no me daria el tiempo

Comment: Guardar en JSON sería la alternativa natural, un json es una representación de un objeto en texto plano que es exactamente lo que buscas, además si estudias algo con la informática no te vas a escapar de aprender json, más temprano que tarde vas a tener que hacerlo, y tampoco es que haya mucho que aprender. La solución que te dieron de los id's es el modo fácil de hacerlo, debes tener un ´array de animales` donde el índice es la id que guardaste entonces para "transformar" tu id en animales haces animales[id]

Comment: Primero que nada aca no realizamos tareas, debes aportat algo del codigo que hayas realizado por tu cuenta y asi la comundad te pueda guiar o darte una solucion. Te invito a visitar el [tour] y de paso tambien leas [ask] para que elabores una buena pregunta!

Comment: Como bien dice @Yussef, en lugar de un `.txt`, deberías trabajar con `JSON`, el cual, en sí mismo es simple, lo aprendes en 15 minutos ([entendiendo esto, tienes un doctorado en JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967)). En un estadio más avanzado de tu aplicación podrás por ejemplo extraer información de la BD, de una API o de donde sea convertida en JSON y con Gson podrás mapear esos datos a clases de tu modelo de datos. Así, si en la clase `Usuario` tienes un campo del tipo `ArrayList<Animal>` Gson los mapeará automáticamente, teniendo a mano toda la información de los ...

Comment: ... animales de ese usuario, de modo que si necesitas mostrar el nombre o lo que sea del animal, podrás hacerlo. Eso sí, tus clases deben estar diseñadas conforme al modelo de datos. Hablamos de una integración en la que participan: tus clases, la fuente de datos (que puede ser la base de datos y/o una API y/o archivos fijos). Si todo está diseñado correctamente, con un par de líneas de código vas a tener mapeado un objeto con todo lo que necesites y luego usarás ese objeto, sus métodos, etc, para mostrar la información. Y si hay objetos anidados en él, también los tendrás.