# como puedo mostrar los datos de este array

Tags: javascript, php, array, json, poo

Como puedo mostrar los datos de este array, tengo un json que lo decodifico para que se transforme en un objeto y luego lo transformo en array, pero a la hora de recorrerlo, no me sale nada

```
 `
 $array=json_decode('
 {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"joel", "email":"joel@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"sara", "email":"sara@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"jorge", "email":"jorge@gmail.com"},  
 {"name":"andres", "email":"andres@gmail.com"} 
',true);

$array=(array) $array;

foreach ($array as  $value) {
  echo "Nombre".$value['name'];
}
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que NO es un array, falta esto `[ ]` para que sea array.

```
 $array=json_decode('
     [
         {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"},
         {"name":"joel", "email":"joel@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"sara", "email":"sara@gmail.com"},
         {"name":"jorge", "email":"jorge@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"andres", "email":"andres@gmail.com"}
     ] 
',true);    

foreach ($array as  $value) {
  printf("Nombre: %s%s",$value['name'],PHP_EOL);
}
```

Salida:

```
Nombre: Shyam
Nombre: Bob
Nombre: Jai
Nombre: joel
Nombre: sara
Nombre: jorge
Nombre: andres
```

Y esto: `$array=(array) $array;` no tiene sentido ninguno en tu código.

Por otra parte, si quieres, puedes pasar `false` a `json_decode` y tratar tus datos como un objeto. La notación en ese caso será `$objeto->propiedad`. Por ejemplo:

```
 $array=json_decode('
     [
         {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"},
         {"name":"joel", "email":"joel@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"sara", "email":"sara@gmail.com"},
         {"name":"jorge", "email":"jorge@gmail.com"},  
         {"name":"andres", "email":"andres@gmail.com"}
     ] 
',false);

foreach ($array as  $value) {
  printf("Nombre: %s%s",$value->name,PHP_EOL);
}
```

La salida será la misma.

---

Te recomiendo [leer esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967), quizá ayude a entender JSON.

Comment: Se me olvido cerrar la pregunta, si exacto me faltaba los corchetes, me di cuenta al momento de subir esta pregunta, muchas gracias por el enlace

Comment: @informaticoDudas no creo que ameritase el cierre, porque el problema, más que un error de ortografía, era sobre la estructura misma del JSON. Por eso he aprovechado también para indicar el enlace, que puede ayudar a entender JSON así como indicar otro modo posible de lectura (como objeto), lo cual puede ser interesante en algunos casos.