# ¿Cómo puedo extraer información especifica de $curl en php?

Tags: php, api

> Buenas, este es el codigo con el cual obtengo los datos de la Api

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"}

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Este es la respuesta y me gustaría saber como obtener el "Summary" porque necesito específicamente el "counting_in","counting_out","day", en resumen me gustaria saber que metodo se utiliza para obtener datos específicos de Curl;

[image]

Comment: Los datos del curl ya los has obtenido. Si quieres datos más específicos usando cUrl entiendo que debes consultar la API a ver si te los da. Pero con lo que ya has obtenido, que parece formato json, seguramente puedes tratarlo con PHP usando json_decode() y que te lo convierta en un array, y de ahí pues lo recorres correctamente para sacar los datos deseados.  Inténtalo y si no lo consigues postea lo que has intentando y el error que te da pulsando sobre [edit] en el pie de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

`$response` es un JSON con datos anidados. Lo que te interesa está en la propiedad `data` del JSON, dicha propiedad a su vez contiene un array de objetos JSON, lo sabemos porque empieza por esto `[` (significa siempre un array) y sigue por esto `{` (significa siempre un objeto). A su vez `summary` contiene un objeto JSON, por lo ya dicho, empieza por `{`.

Entendido eso, puedes encontrar lo que buscas usando `json_decode()`, que convertirá `$response` en un JSON, en el cual podrás buscar cualquier objeto, array, valor, según la ubicación del mismo en el JSON.

Veamos un ejemplo, usaremos una versión reducida de tu variable `$response` por brevedad.

```
$response='{
   "cod":200,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "summary":{
            "counting_in":266,
            "counting_out":333,
            "day":"2022-12-01"
         }
      }
   ]
}';

$json=json_decode($response);
#En data podría haber varios objetos
#Aquí accedemos al primero, índice 0
$summary=$json->data[0]->summary;
var_dump($summary);
```

**Salida**:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
  ["counting_in"]=>
  int(266)
  ["counting_out"]=>
  int(333)
  ["day"]=>
  string(10) "2022-12-01"
}
```

Como ves, `$summary` contiene todos tus datos, y puedes mostrarlos con algo tan simple como:

```
echo $summary->counting_in.PHP_EOL;
echo $summary->counting_out.PHP_EOL;
echo $summary->day.PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
266
333
2022-12-01
```

Supongamos que quieras leer todos los objetos que hay en `data`:

```
$response='{
   "cod":200,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "summary":{
            "counting_in":266,
            "counting_out":333,
            "day":"2022-12-01"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "summary":{
            "counting_in":267,
            "counting_out":334,
            "day":"2022-12-02"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "summary":{
            "counting_in":268,
            "counting_out":335,
            "day":"2022-12-03"
         }
      }      
   ]
}';
$json=json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->data as $item) {
    echo $item->id.PHP_EOL;
    $summary=$item->summary;
    echo $summary->counting_in.PHP_EOL; #También puedes acceder así: $item->summary->counting_in
    echo $summary->counting_out.PHP_EOL;
    echo $summary->day.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1
266
333
2022-12-01

2
267
334
2022-12-02

3
268
335
2022-12-03
```

Como ves, JSON es muy simple, si comprendes lo esencial, podrás leer cualquier respuesta, por compleja que sea su anidación. Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967), si entiendes lo dicho allí, ningún JSON se te va a resistir.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue muy util.

Comment: @Angel si la respuesta ha servido para resolver tu problema considera marcarla como aceptada, activando la flecha gris que aparece en la parte superior izquierda, así la pregunta no aparecerá como sin responder, y la respuesta dada podrá servir a futuros usuarios con un problema parecido. Saludos.