# Cual es la mejor opcion para mandar hacer varios llamados al servidor desde android?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

Cual seria la opción ideal para mandar varios registros al servidor desde android, hasta el momento uso volley, pero cuando llego a mas de 1000 registros la aplicación colapsa, que me supongo que es por la cantidad de proceso que esta haciendo en ese momento.

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Conexiones.REGISTRAR_PRODUCTO,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                    Integer http_response = Integer.parseInt(ServerResponse);

                }
            }
            ,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    
                    //Toast.makeText(AgregarProductos.this, "Error al conectar con el servidor, revise que ningun campo este nulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            // Creating Map String Params.
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Adding All values to Params.
            // The firs argument should be same sa your MySQL database table columns.
            params.put("categoria", categoria1);
            params.put("marca", marca1);
            params.put("tipo", tipo1);
            params.put("modelo", modelo1);
            params.put("ano", ano1);
            params.put("dprincipal", dprincipal1);
            params.put("dcomplementaria", dcomplementaria1);
            params.put("medidas", medidas1);
            params.put("precio", precio1);
            params.put("stock", stock1);
            params.put("codigo", codigo1);
            params.put("id", Preferences.obtenerPreferenceString(AgregarProductos.this, Preferences.PREFERENCE_USER_ID));


            return params;
        }

    };

    // Creating RequestQueue.
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));

   // RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS);
    //stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    stringRequest.setShouldCache(true);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest); ´´
```

**Intente pausar cada 5 segundos, pero igual colapsa, existe alguna otra forma?**

Comment: Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué mandas varias peticiones? Si tienes a mano todos los datos, poco importa sin son unos pocos miles, no deberías tener problemas si los mandas todos juntos. Aunque siempre depende de varios factores, como la velocidad de la conexión, la capacidad del servidor remoto al que mandas la petición etc. Si son datos masivos, por ejemplo, decenas de miles, puedes pensar en paginar. Lo que no debes hacer es querer mandarlos uno por uno. No tiene sentido, porque cada envío es costoso en sí mismo.

Comment: Es conveniente revisar las bitácoras del servidor; concuerdo en que deberías enviar mas registros por petición observando el tamaño máximo de POST configurado en el servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si exacto, pero no se exactamente como mandar todos esos datos de una vez al servidor. Horita solo envío un registro al servidor, cada 5 segundo con volley. Que puedo implementar para mandar ese arreglo completo?

Comment: Es muy sencillo. En la lógica de tu programa, tendrías que preocuparte por crear un array de objetos JSON, algo así por ejemplo: `[{"id":1, "name":"Pedro"},{"id":2, "name":"Marta"},{"id":3, "name":"Juan"}]`, ese array tiene tres objetos como podrás comprobar, pero pueden ser más, hasta el máximo permitido, lo cual depende del servidor, de la velocidad de la conexión, del tamaño de cada JSON (no es lo mismo un JSON con un id y un nombre que un JSON con texto largo por ejemplo) ... lo cierto es que puedes enviar por lo general varias decenas o centenas al mismo tiempo ...

Comment: ... luego, en el servidor, debes escribir código para leer ese array de objetos, es simplemente parsearlo como array y leer cada elemento dentro de un bucle, no tiene mayor dificultad. Es simplemente una cuestión de organización. JSON en realidad es muy sencillo, sólo tienes que leer los datos conforme a como estén organizados y garantizar que estás creando siempre un JSON que sea válido.

Comment: Dado que vas a trabajar enviando/recibiendo datos entre el cliente y el servidor, con Volley, y, muy probablemente con Retrofit más adelante, te recomiendo que leas [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429573/29967) y la tengas en mente, para que las cosas no se te hagan un mundo, como de hecho ocurre en este caso. Quizá por no entender la sencillez de JSON estás enviando las peticiones una por una, cuando puedes organizar varios objetos en un `JSONArray` y enviarlos todos juntos en una sola petición, ahorrándote un montón de recursos.